# Dict values to array, sorted by key

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
test_dict = {"1": "one", "3": "three", "2": "two"}
```

I'd like to create an array of values, but sorted by key, to get something like this:

```
test_array = ["one", "two", "three"]
```

Normally, I retrieve values by using test_dict.values(), but since dictionaries are unordered, it messes up my array.

Comment: @accdias: `sorted()` returns a list, lists don't have a `.values()` method.

Comment: Yeah... I know and that's why I deleted the comment. I meant to write this `dict(sorted(test_dict.items())).values()`. Kind of a hack though.

Comment: Someone posted this `[x[1] for x in sorted(test_dict.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0]))]` which seems to do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: If you want without using OrderedDict you can use something like this `values =  [x[1] for x in sorted(data.items(), key = lambda x:x[0])]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
test_dict = {"1": "one", "3": "three", "2": "two"}

print([x[1] for x in sorted(test_dict.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0]))])
# ['one', 'two', 'three']
```